# Apache2: 400 Bad Request with Rewrite Rules, nothing in error log?

Tags: php, logging, mod-rewrite, apache-2.2

This is driving me nuts.

Background: I'm using the built-in Apache2 & PHP that comes with Mac OS X 10.6

I have a vhost setup as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:81

<Directory "/Users/neezer/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName lobster.dev
    ServerAlias *.lobster.dev
    DocumentRoot /Users/neezer/Sites/lobster/www

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog /private/var/log/apache2/lobster_error
</VirtualHost>
```

This is in `/private/etc/apache2/users/neezer.conf`.

My code in the `lobster project` is PHP with the [CodeIgniter framework](http://codeigniter.com/). Trying to load http://lobster.dev:81/ gives me:

> 400 Bad Request

Normally, I'd go check my logs to see what caused it, yet my logs are empty! I looked in both `/private/var/log/apache2/error_log` and `/private/var/log/apache2/lobster_error`, and neither records ANY message relating to the 400. I have `LogLevel` set to `debug` in `/private/etc/apache2/http.conf`.

Removing the rewrite rules gets rid of the error, but these same rules work on my MAMP host. I've double-checked and `rewrite_module` is loaded in my default Apache installation. My `http.conf` can be found here: https://gist.github.com/1057091

What gives? Let me know if you need any additional info.

NOTE: I do NOT want to add the rewrite rules to `.htaccess` in the project directory (it's checked into a git repo and I don't want to touch it).

Comment: You looked in the log of php?

Comment: I can't seem to even get my php log up. You can see my `php.ini` file here: https://gist.github.com/1057384

Comment: I think that you get this error, when write yourdomain.com ? What happens when you try to Referring to yourdomain.com/index.php  ?

Comment: Same thing when trying anything on the site, even /index.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For complicated mod_rewrite rules, it's a good idea to log the sequence of events to see what's happening. Do this using [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog), and crank up the [RewriteLogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLogLevel) to see the details.

mod_rewrite is very flexible and one can do many things with the rewrite rules, and is also quite complicated. An outsider will have trouble debugging your rules without seeing the broader context. The best thing you can do debug it on your own. Watch the logs in one window while you experiment with configuration changes in a second window. Make a small change, save the file, reload apache and hit the URL again. Repeat.

Here's a good description of RewriteLog from the Apache [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#other):

> **Rewrite Log**
>
> When using the powerful
>   and complex features of mod_rewrite,
>   it is almost always necessary to use
>   the RewriteLog to help in debugging.
>   This log file produces a detailed
>   analysis of how the rewriting engine
>   transforms requests. The level of
>   detail is controlled by the
>   RewriteLogLevel directive.

Comment: Ok, it was trying to load `index.php//index.php`, and that was the issue. I've since change the rule to read `RewriteRule ^\/(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]` at it works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your substitution in `<virtualhost>` context uses a non-absolute URL.  You can't do this outside of Directory/htaccess context.

Comment: Thanks this was my issue: `RewriteRule ~/(.+) something.php/$1` -> `RewriteRule ~/(.+) /something.php/$1` fixed it

Comment: that was it for me too. Moved things from directory context into general context and had to change the rewrite rule on both sides

Answer (score 3):

A few other notes, which became a bit too large to be contained in a mere comment:

`RewriteCond $1` works, but it's quite dangerous and brittle.  In particular, you could easily have rewritten the RewriteRule so as to disable the functionality of that RewriteCond altogether, and you'd never know you had.  The use of `%{REQUEST_URI}` is recommended as a solution, à la `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)`.

Next issue: these two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

are not functional as presented.  They either need to be placed inside a `<Directory>` stanza, or modified to use the look-ahead macros (e.g. `RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`).

The actual cause of you needing to remove the `/` is that `.htaccess` strips off the leading `/` from the first argument of RewriteRule, whereas it's delivered with `/` intact to RewriteRules in httpd.conf (or its `Include`d files), which is something important to remember in case you ever try to move this rule back into a .htaccess.  You can rework the Rule to be .htaccess/httpd.conf-agnostic by doing something like `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`.

One last note: as you can see in the rule, above, you don't need to escape the `/` with a backslash.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I had just copy/pasted this in the heat of the moment, but I'll definitely go back and revisit these rules as you suggested.